# Why is main() in java void?

Tags: java

In the case of languages with a C-like syntax, we declare the main() method to return an int or float value (or void).  Is it possible to declare a non-void return type from main() in Java?  If not, then why not?  Does this mean that a Java program doesn't return any value to the OS?

Comment: In what language does `main` return a floating-point value?

Comment: As the top voted answer to this question indicates, there is a technical reason for this, so it is not primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 73):

The `main()` method must indeed have a `void` return type. From the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) on "Execution - Virtual Machine Start-Up" ([§12.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html)):

> The method `main` must be declared
>   `public`, `static`, and **`void`**. It must
>   accept a single argument that is an
>   array of strings.

It goes on to describe when a program exits in "Execution - Program Exit" ([§12.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#44857)):

> A program terminates all its activity
>   and *exits* when one of two things
>   happens:
>
> - All the threads that are not
>     daemon threads terminate.
> - Some thread
>     invokes the `exit` method of class
>     `Runtime` or class `System` and the exit
>     operation is not forbidden by the
>     security manager.

In other words, the program may exit before or after the `main` method finishes; a return value from `main` would therefore be meaningless.
If you want the program to return a status code, call one of the following methods (note that all three methods never return normally):

- [`System.exit(int status)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) - Equivalent to `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(status)`
- [`Runtime.exit(int status)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int)) - Terminates the currently running JVM by initiating its shutdown sequence (run all registered [shutdown hooks](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)), and [uninvoked finalizers](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#runFinalizersOnExit(boolean)), if necessary). Once this is done the JVM halts.
- [`Runtime.halt(int status)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt(int)) - Forcibly terminates the currently running JVM.

Of the three, `System.exit()` is the conventional and most convenient way to terminate the JVM.

Answer (score 29):

[This](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t135045-why-does-main-in-java-returns-void-.html) is an interesting discussion on `velocityreviews` on the same topic:

Highlight:

> Incidentally, this is considered bad style in C and C++ just because
>   it's the *wrong* signature for main, not for any universal reason
>   independent of programming languages. It's one of those things that is
>   not really supposed to work, but might on your implementation.
>
> In Java, the reason main returns void is threads. C and C++ were both
>   designed as languages before multithreading was a widely known
>   technique, and both had threads grafted onto them at a later date. Java
>   was designed from the beginning to be a multithreaded environment, and
>   frankly, it would be unusual to write any non-trivial Java application
>   that doesn't use more than one thread. So the idea that a program moves
>   linearly from the beginning to the end of main is a bit outdated.

written by

> www.designacourse.com
>   The Easiest Way to Train Anyone... Anywhere.
>   Chris Smith - Lead Software Developer/Technical Trainer
>   MindIQ Corporation

Answer (score 26):

The reason for the `main` method having `void` as return type is that once `main` finishes, it doesn't necessarily mean that the entire program finished. If `main` spawns new threads, then these threads can keep program running. The return type of `main` doesn't make much sense at this point.

For example, this is very common in Swing applications, where the `main` method typically starts a GUI on the Swing thread, and then `main` finishes... but the program is still running.

Comment: Peter, could you clarify for myself (currently exploring java multithreading)... Is it deamon threads ONLY that are NOT permitted to outlive main() ?

Comment: @Max: no, main() method has no control over JVM. When JVM starts, it will run main() method, but when main() finishes, it doesn't mean that JVM terminaes. JVM continues to execute all threads until 1) Runtime.exit() is called OR 2) all normal (not daemon) threads have died. Daemon threads do not count for this second condition.

In other words ... if main() method spawns some normal threads, JVM will **not** terminate when main() finishes. If main() doesn't spawn any threads, JVM will terminate. If main() spawns only daemon threads, JVM will also terminate when main() finishes.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me out of all the answers.

Answer (score 7):

You can return an int with System.exit().

Returning anything other than an integer doesn't make much sense, as the OS expects an integer. In case nothing is returned the default is 0, which means OK. Other values typically are used to signal errors or special conditions.