# Why does eclipse require an actual method called 'main'?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio

How come in Eclipse if I don't specifically have a method called `main` and more specifically make that `main` method `static`, I get an error saying `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`?   While in an Android Studio project, not only is there no method called `main`, the first method called in `MyActivity.class` is `onCreate` which isn't `static`.

Comment: Some main method is not main.

Comment: Java requires a method `public static void main` with a `String[]` argument.  This is standard Java and has nothing to do with Eclipse.  See section 12.1.4 of the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html).  Android is different because an application can have more than one entry point that the OS can call, and (I think) because Google just likes being different.

Comment: Related questions: [2 Main methods with different signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194793/2-main-methods-with-different-signatures) and [Why main method is marked as public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666421/why-main-method-is-marked-as-public).

Answer (score 2):

A Java class's main entry point will always have the signature:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

With Android, you are not simply running a Java program, you are running code inside a container.  Because of that, the container can set any entry point it likes.