# Is there any performance loss

Tags: java

```
public class Mayank {

public static void main(String ...aa){
  System.out.println("Yes it is working");
       }
}
```

Is there any decrease in efficiency of program,if we use this syntax.

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: Why it support variable arguments  and why we generally not use it in main methos.Any specific reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not showing you a compilation error, because although the formatting is all over the place, the code is syntactically correct.

BTW  The `String...` is an ellipsis which is like a `String[]` and is fine to use. (I prefer it)

I would get your IDE to format it like this

```
public class Mayank {
    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        System.out.println("Yes it is working");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because there is nothing wrong with the code.

You can refer to this Q&A to get a clear view.
[public static void main(String arg[ ] ) in java is it fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028589/public-static-void-mainstring-arg-in-java-is-it-fixed)

Answer (score 1):

main method in java accepts String array arguments so all the following are valid types

```
public static void main(String ...aa){


public static void main(String[] aa){


public static void main(String []aa){


public static void main(String aa[]){

public static void main(String [] aa){
```

As per your updated post varargs means variable arguments.If you are not sure how many arguements you want to pass then you can use varargs.

**Note that** varargs only support **java 5 onwards**.So if you are using java version older than 5 then this will definitely show you error

Answer (score 0):

main(String... args) can just run in jdk1.5+,and main(String[] args) can run in each version.and is there 's any difference as u never call the method directly?