# How java interpreter picks up main function even when it is placed in inner class?

Tags: java

We declare `main` function as `public` and `static` because Java interpreter should have access to it and there need not be object of the class to call `main` function. When I created `main` function within inner class and run the class, then also `main` function got executed. 
How does interpreter work internally to pick the `main` function and to execute?

Comment: Java is not an interpreted language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952804/java-explanation-of-public-static-void-mainstring-args

Comment: Do you have any code to back your explanation.  I am unclear as to what the actual question is.

Comment: @August that is not entirely true.. Java can be an interpreted language, and infact most JVMs ship with both an interpreter (for fast startup) and a JIT which is used to optimise 'hotspots'.

Comment: @August Not really true. Java is a "hybrid": Code gets _compiled_ to bytecode, which then gets _interpreted_ by the JVM.

Comment: A `public static void main(String[])` in an inner class Inner inside a class Outer is just as static. In fact you will see a class file `Outer$Innner.class` compiled, containing such a function. Also in that main, there will be no `this` or `Outer.this`.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me fix your question. As it was already mentioned by @August java is not an interpreted language. I believe that asking about interpreter you want to ask about JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

Now the answer. I guess that JVM uses reflection call to execute `main()` method, i.e. uses code similar to the following:

```
Class mainClass = Class.forName(mainClassName); // mainClassName is taken from the command line argument. 
Method main = mainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
method.invoke(args); // args are taken from command line
```

Answer (score 1):

Signature of main method in Java

The main method has to strictly follow its syntax; otherwise the JVM will not be able to locate it and your program will not run. Here is the exact signature of main method:

**`public static void main(String args[])`**

If a program does not have this signature then the JVM will not able to find main method.

In this signature ..........

`public` defines that this method is accessible out of class, 
`static` shows that this method is accessible without creating any object of class,
`void` shows that this method will not return any value,
`String args` defines no. of argument is passed by user.

If the  above signature does not match the JVM will return main method not found exception.

Comment: If some day this link broke the answer will be not valid. Put something to answer and then you can refer the site.

Comment: Ok @Cold i modify answer