# Member function accepts values when called separately but not when called in main function

Tags: java

The program I wrote

```
public class Angle{
int deg1,deg2, min1,min2;
    void accept()throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the angle parameters degree fb minute fb next degree");
    deg1= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    min1= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    deg2= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    min2= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}
int anglesum(int a,int b,int x, int y)
{
    int m= (int)(b+y)/60;

    int s=a+x+m;
    return(s);
}
void main()throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Angle abc=new Angle();
    abc.accept();
    int e=abc.anglesum(deg1,min1,deg2,min2);
    System.out.println("The sum is ="+e+" degrees "+(min1+min2-60)+" minutes");
}
```

It accepts values when calling functions separately via object but not when running main function. What could be the problem?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "but no when running main function" - what happens, and what did you expect? It would help if you'd provide a [mcve], and ideally follow Java naming conventions too... (The fact that you're opening a `BufferedReader` around `System.in` twice seems suspicious, btw. Ideally, hard-code the data in your example code.)

Comment: Your class is full with problems: A) you violate java naming convents; class names go UpperCase **always**; whereas methods and variables should be using camelCase. B) really bad naming - use names that tell something, avoid single char names C) normally, **main** should be static and taking a string array. You should step back; and rethink what you actually want to achieve; and then add those things one by one; and after each step you run the compiler!

Comment: Since i am relatively new to programming I couldn't decide what parts to put in. Sorry for inconvenience. On creating `new angle()` and calling classes separately in the bottom bar the program works perfectly. But when calling the main function `s` returns as null. That's all, I think.I am adding `deg1` and `deg2` normally and adding `min1` and `min2` until the sum reaches 60 wherein the spillover gets printed separately while an entire 60 cycle adds as 1 to the sum of `deg1` and `deg2`. Hope that clears stuff.

Comment: Your main method should be like this `public static void main(String[] args){`. Read about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952804/explanation-of-string-args-and-static-in-public-static-void-mainstring-a

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you are calling method `main` that is method of object `Angle` and inside you are creating instance of another object of type `Angle`

You may change `int e=abc.anglesum(deg1,min1,deg2,min2);` 
to 
`int e=abc.anglesum(abc.deg1, abc.min1, abc.deg2, abc.min2);`
then you probably get the result you want.

Same for `System.out.println("The sum is ="+e+" degrees "+(abc.min1 + abc.min2-60)+" minutes");`

1) You should move method main so that it is not part of object `Angle`

2) You may create new method in `Angle`

```
int anglesum() { return anglesum(deg1,min1,deg2,min2); }
```

then you may call in your main method (that will no longer be part of `Angle`):

```
abc.accept();
int e=abc.anglesum();
```