# java.nio.file not workin in java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
public class debugImageMain {
    public static void main() throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    }
}
```

But when I run I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   pdc.conversor.debugImageMain.main([Ljava.lang.String;)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)

javac -version gives: javac 1.8.0_60 and I have java VERSION 8 Update 91.

IntelliJ tell me java.nio.file imports are underlined in red and says "Usages of API which isn't available at the configured language level.

Any help please???

Comment: no it work your main method is not correct ;) it should be `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {`

Comment: And in "Project structure", you probably selected Java 6 (or lower) as your language level, instead of Java 8, hence the warning.

Comment: Please post the entire error message

Comment: The stack trace shows clearly that `java.nio.file` has exactly nothing to do with it.

Comment: *"java.nio.file not workin in java 8"* ... Java is 20 years old.  Its libraries have been continuously developed for many years.  It requires a peculiar form of arrogance to conclude that an error in a program you have written must reside in the Java libraries ... rather than in the code you have written.

Comment: @scottb very hepfull.... I didn't write "java.nio.file not workin in java 8 because Java is wrong" you just concluded I thought it was java fault... I wrote it that way because all over the internet it says java.nio.file doesn't work in java 6 or lower... so to avoid people to tell me that my java version was old... because it was java 8 then the problem couldn't be java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `java.nio.file`, the problem is in the definition of `main` signature.

- The only way to running a program in Java is with the specific `public static void main (String [] args)` signature.

To fix your current statement, change this:

```
public static void main() throws IOException {
```

For this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
```

*Check it out these entries [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java), and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28456889)*

Comment: It worked... as IntelliJ underlined in red the java.nio.file it led me to believe the problem was there... But it was a complicatedly different issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Java required the main method to be definded correctly which is the entry point to run the app.

Try:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
public class debugImageMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, Java naming convention is to have Class name starts in Capital.

Comment: you are right... my bad... thanks for the advise about the convention.