# Passing java results to command line

Tags: java, command-line

I was thinking of passing the result from Java run from command line into a command line variable. But after searching much for it, I only came across Runtime class which just runs the command.

Therefore, my question, is there anything I can do to get Java result into command line.

Platform of course is Windows.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  In most situations, stdout is directed to your shell/console.  Is this not what you're seeing?

Comment: Command line variable?  Do you mean the String [] args array passed to main into other objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set environment variables from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

Comment: @duffymo, yes but instead of passing into main. Getting a value after main completes.

Comment: From my personal experience, make sure you call java.exe and not javaw.exe (which is what the IDE usually calls)

Comment: @Ahsan, this makes no sense to me at all.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

There are only 2 ways any program (Java or otherwise) can send results back to the "command line":

1) exit code

2) capture the strings output by the program.

#1 can be done in Java using System.exit (or [see a couple more options here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/540486/1118101)).

#2 is done by the shell. In Unix, you typically use backticks or $():

```
OUTPUT=`java app.class`
```

In Windows Powershell, do something like

```
$result = & java app.class 2>&1 | Out-String
```

Comment: Java has `void main`, so only `System.exit()` for #1. I think #2 is what the OP meant, though that has nothing to do with Java

Comment: ouch! right, Java has void main. Thanks! edited.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of
[how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows)

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('java Main') DO set today=%i
```

Also allows today variable to be set.