# kotlin springboot application - why no function with expression body?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

In my (2.0.0.M6) kotlin-spring boot app, everything works fine when I do

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```

but the mainClass can not be found and IDEA does not allow running the app when I do

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runApplication<RankedApplication>(*args)
```

this is not critical at all, but I wonder: why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`runApplication` does not return `Unit`.

The signature and return type of `main` *must* be exactly:

```
fun main(Array<String>): Unit
```

`runApplication`, though, [returns a `ConfigurableApplicationContext`](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplicationExtensions.kt#L31).

Your "main" method is equivalent to:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): ConfigurableApplicationContext {
    return runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```

since the return type is deduced from the expression - and you can see this is not a valid entry point.

Your first method works because

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```

is the same as

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
    runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
    return Unit
}
```

since `Unit` (a singleton object) is the default return type when none is specified, and is implicitly returned at the end of a method declared to return `Unit`.

This is also why `return` without an argument is valid - it just returns `Unit`.

---

If you wanted to, you could make a method to convert things to `Unit` though this is probably overkill.

```
inline fun Unit(lambda: () -> Any?) {
    lambda()
}

...

fun main(args: Array<String>) = Unit { runApplication<MyApplication>(*args) }
```

---

[It's the same in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/540486/7366707), which is likely where this requirement comes from - the main method's signature must be `public static void main(String[])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```

`main` returns `Unit` here implicitely which is correct.

Here

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runApplication<RankedApplication>(*args)
```

the return type is inferred from the given expression to something other than `Unit` (because `runApplication` returns something) which does not work because the main function has to return `Unit`.